# What are versions used for in Jira?

Tags: jira

I have a scrum project in Jira and I have discovered that I can drag & drop issues to the versions sub menu to assign an issue to a specific version. However, there is no restriction for mixing up versions in the same sprint. I could have, for example, 2 stories in sprint 1 going for version 0.1 and 2 going for version 0.2. How is this used?

Answer (score 1):

Versions in Jira map directly to [configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) or [versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) of your product, although not all products are explicitly versioned.

There's no restriction or relationship between a Sprint and a version because your team may be supporting multiple versions of a single product. As you add bug fixes or new features, you would want to keep track of which versions those fixes are targeting (as you develop them) or were part of (once you make the version available). You can allocate issues to multiple versions, if that's appropriate, as well - I'm not sure if you can do this in the drag-and-drop part of the user interface, but you can when you edit issues.